# Github hooks to update internal issues

Tags: github

Github provides issue management as part of their service. This provides a convenient way to integrate source version control together with light project management in a form of milestones and issues.

Is there a way to set up a repository receive hook in order to update relevant issues (somehow specified in commit messages) by automatically adding comments with the content of the commit messages?

Comment: GitHub already posts a comment to an issue when a commit is pushed to the GitHub repository that mentions the issue.

Comment: One thing that does not seem to be mentioned in answers to the original question, is how to reference an issue without closing it. The answer is trivial -- simply put #issue-number into the commit message.

Answer (score 0):

[From the Github help pages](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages):

> When you enter "Fixes #45" into a commit message, issue #45 is closed once that commit is merged into your default branch. If the bug isn't fixed in your default branch, the issue remains open. Once the commit with the fix is merged into your default branch, the issue is automatically closed.
>
> If you make a commit in a non-default branch with the "Fixes #33" syntax, the issue is referenced with a tooltip.
>
> You can use any of the following keywords to close an issue via commit message:
>
> ```
> close
> closes
> closed
> fix
> fixes
> fixed
> resolve
> resolves
> resolved
> ```